# textarea,js,php

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы данные (в данном случае 4 цифры) из textarea брались как var и чтобы их можно было сравнить с другими переменными используя if...else и выводить как alert();

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

js:

```
var el;
var text;

el = document.getElementById("text");
text = el.value;

//тут можно делать что хочется с text

document.onclick = function(){
 allert(text);
}
```